# Horizontal Scroll on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Does anybody knows how to implement horizontal scrolling on event? I am trying to replicate this functionality: http://www.spotify-valentines.com/#/home
First, it scrolls fullpage to the right. Then, it scrolls half way to the right. Then it scrolls full page, also to the right, and finally it becomes a normal screen with vertical scrolling.
The site seems to be built with Angular, but I am not sure how this functionality is accomplished.

Thanks!

Comment: What about using a content slider in jquery? However it scrolls always to a new full page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be accomplish by using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Just create a single section with multiple slides in. Then you can create your custom buttons and associate them with the action `$.fn.fullpage.moveTo()` or `$.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight()` or `$.fn.fullpage.moveSlideLeft()`.